# Getting started with NPM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to get started with ReactJS on an existing project. I'm following instructions [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project) to install NodeJS and Babel, but failing at the second step.

I have installed NodeJS on Windows, correctly as far as I can tell. I've navigated my terminal to the root folder of my Flask app and typed `npm init -y`. This generates a `package.json` file in the root of my app. I think this is correct so far.

However, when I try to run the next command in the [instructions](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project) `npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3` I receive the following error:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Rob\Dropbox\Andon\andon> npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\yallist\package.json
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\yallist\yallist.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-20T12_55_30_568Z-debug.log
```

In fact, I receive that error when I try to run any `npm install` commands. I assume there is some problem with how I've setup NPM, but this is my first time using it and I have no idea.

Any help would be appreciated, please.

EDIT: This is the full log of the error:

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'babel-cli@6',
1 verbose cli   'babel-preset-react-app@3'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\yallist\yallist.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
4 verbose stack     at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:319:19)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:18)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:27)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\minipass\index.js:3:17)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\extract-stream.js:3:18)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Rob\Dropbox\Andon\andon
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "babel-cli@6" "babel-preset-react-app@3"
8 verbose node v12.16.2
9 verbose npm  v6.14.4
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\yallist\package.json
12 error Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\yallist\yallist.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Hi @Rob, at least for me the error is not obvious. Did you take a look into the log file (last line): _C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-20T12_55_30_568Z-debug.log_

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg Sure, it's too long to paste here but I'll edit my question to include it.

Comment: Deleting the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` then running `npm install` generally works which situations like this if you have downloaded npm correctly.

Comment: @CeyhunAslan One thing I noticed is that after initialising `npm` I don't have a `node_modules` folder or a `package-lock.json` file. I only have `package.json`. Have I missed a step?

Comment: Hi @Rob,
thanks for the log. I still don't see where the reference to `pacote` is coming from. At least on my machine the install works and I donnot see any reference ot `pacote`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sometimes such problems are related to the fact Node is installed in a path with spaces ( ie "Program Files" ) try to install somewhere else in a folder without spaces.

Comment: That has never been a problem for me. Also, where else would you install it? Literally all the paths on windows have spaces in them. :)

Comment: @Felice I'm not sure if this is exactly the solution, but it worked. I reinstalled NodeJS into `C:\Node` and it works correctly now. I'm not sure if it was the reinstall or the fact it's not in `Program Files` any more, but it works. So thank you.

Comment: the -1 comes from npm developer who won't fix the problem